# Add project reference to Swift iOS XCode project and debug

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, xcode6

I am beginning development both an iPhone and iPad product and the two will use a custom framework for core functionality.  I have created an iOS Framework project that will contain all the common API's.  I would like to be able to debug the framework while debugging the iPhone app.  I have added both the iPhone and Framework projects to my work space and linked the framework to my iPhone project.  When ever I try to clean or build the project I get this error.

MyFramework is not a valid PRODUCT_NAME for use with framework targets enabling DEFINES_MODULE (name is not a valid C99 extended identifier).  This is in XCode 6

Anyone have any ideas what this means?

Thank you.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It means that the name of you framework is not valid.
It coitains some not reserved characters.

**`-`** Can't be used in Framework name

**Example:**

`MyFrameroks-iOS` - Wrong
`MyFrameroksiOS` - Correct

Try to rename you framework. Seach for `product name` in project build setting and change it
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for taking so long to  give you credit.

Answer (score 16):

Just to add to @Kostiantyn Koval's answer: the default value of the Product Name field is `$(TARGET_NAME)`, which takes the value from the Target Name, as implied. By changing that to `$(TARGET_NAME:c99extidentifier)`, you can supply a c99-compatible string that will stay in sync with the Target Name, as the default value does. Apple is using that in e.g. the Product Module Name property (where it appears as `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)`)

In practice, what this does is to change some incompatible characters, such as whitespaces, with compatible ones, such as underscore in this case.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that indeed it changes white spaces to underscore.

Comment: Dots "." seem to be another character that causes this problem. This approach fixes it - turning them into underscores as well.